# Moving displayed data from Qt table to sqlite3 db

Tags: python, qt, sqlite, pyside

I am new to python but have been able to create a pyside qt gui and fill the various boxes and a table with data from my application.  Basically it gets a test file reference from one .csf file and test criteria from another .csv file and fills the qt GUI with the results of the test application.  One of my GUI action buttons is supposed to take the data from boxes and all rows in the table and input into an sqlite3 database named "testresults.db"  I can create the database table with the headers.  I want to get gui data from some of the boxes and all the table data for each row into the testresults database.  I have seen lots of examples of moving data FROM a .db to Gui but none coming the other way.  Below is the header info from my main application and also the GUI code.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
from PySide.QtGui import *  
from ui_files import pyExpMainWindow    
import sys  
import sqlite3
import csv
import time
import os


class Main(QMainWindow, pyExpMainWindow.Ui_MainWindow):  
    dbPath =(os.getcwd() + "\TestData.db")  
    dbConn = sqlite3.connect(dbPath)
    def __init__(self, parent=None, index=None):   
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)  
        self.setupUi(self) 

        self.dbCursor = self.dbConn.cursor()
        self.dbCursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Main(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                                assypartno TEXT, userialno TEXT, bserialno TEXT, testfile TEXT, desc TEXT,
                                expectedvalue TEXT, actualvalue TEXT, lowlimit TEXT, highlimit TEXT,
                                 status TEXT, time TEXT, opername TEXT)""")
        self.dbConn.commit()    # creates table if file doesn't exist
        self.start.clicked.connect(self.Start_T)
        self.repeat.clicked.connect(self.Repeat_Test)
        self.record.clicked.connect(self.Record_R)
        self._print.clicked.connect(self.Print_Report)
        self.cancel.clicked.connect(self.Cancel_Testing)
        self.load_initial_settings()

        with open("testprogs.csv", "rb") as f:  # testprogs.csv is the list of testable assemblies
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                line = row[0]   
                if line[0] == "#":  
                    continue
                self.partno.addItem(row[1])  

    def load_initial_settings(self):
        """Loads the initial settings for the application. Sets the mainTable column widths,"""
        self.dbCursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM Main""")
        allRows = []    #Specifies a blank table so table just fills with header info
        for row in allRows:
            inx = allRows.index(row)
            self.mainTable.insertRow(inx)
            self.mainTable.setItem(inx, 0, QTableWidgetItem(row[1]))
            self.mainTable.setItem(inx, 1, QTableWidgetItem(row[2]))
            self.mainTable.setItem(inx, 2, QTableWidgetItem(row[3]))
            self.mainTable.setItem(inx, 3, QTableWidgetItem(row[4]))
************************************************************


# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file '.\experiment.ui'
#
# Created: Wed Jul 09 07:02:46 2014
#      by: pyside-uic 0.2.15 running on PySide 1.2.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(865, 738)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.start = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.start.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 30, 75, 23))
        self.start.setObjectName("start")
        self.partno = QtGui.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.partno.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 151, 22))
        self.partno.setEditable(True)
        self.partno.setObjectName("partno")
        self.repeat = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.repeat.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 30, 75, 23))
        self.repeat.setObjectName("repeat")
        self.cancel = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.cancel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(640, 80, 75, 23))
        self.cancel.setObjectName("cancel")
        self.record = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.record.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 30, 75, 23))
        self.record.setObjectName("record")
        self._print = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self._print.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 80, 75, 23))
        self._print.setObjectName("_print")
        self.description = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.description.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 151, 20))
        self.description.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.description.setObjectName("description")
        self._operator = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self._operator.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 80, 113, 20))
        self._operator.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self._operator.setObjectName("_operator")
        self.unit_serialno = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.unit_serialno.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 80, 113, 20))
        self.unit_serialno.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.unit_serialno.setObjectName("unit_serialno")
        self.testno = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.testno.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 30, 113, 20))
        self.testno.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.testno.setObjectName("testno")
        self.brd_serialno = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.brd_serialno.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 110, 113, 20))
        self.brd_serialno.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.brd_serialno.setObjectName("brd_serialno")
        self.mainTable = QtGui.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.mainTable.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 150, 811, 541))
        self.mainTable.setObjectName("mainTable")
        self.mainTable.setColumnCount(5)
        self.mainTable.setRowCount(0)
        item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.mainTable.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.mainTable.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.mainTable.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.mainTable.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.mainTable.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.partno, QtCore.SIGNAL("currentIndexChanged(int)"), MainWindow.update)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.start.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Start", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.repeat.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Repeat Test", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.cancel.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Cancel", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.record.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Record", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self._print.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Print Report", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.description.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Description", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self._operator.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Operator Name", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.unit_serialno.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Unit Serial #", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.testno.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Test #", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.brd_serialno.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Board Serial #", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.mainTable.horizontalHeaderItem(0).setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Test", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.mainTable.horizontalHeaderItem(1).setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Description", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.mainTable.horizontalHeaderItem(2).setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Expected", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.mainTable.horizontalHeaderItem(3).setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Actual", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.mainTable.horizontalHeaderItem(4).setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Pass/Fail", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

Comment: Don't try to reinvent the wheel - use [QSqlTableModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsqltablemodel.html).

Comment: Remembering that I am new to python, I tried many perturbations of "QSqlTableModel" and could not find one that the compiler was happy with an trying to connect to my MainWindow table..